# permutation graph $G$ and it's complement

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a permutation graph

By definition if $\pi$ is a permutation of $\{1...n \}$ the vertices $i,j$ are connected by an edge if and only if $ i\lt j $ and $\pi_i \gt \pi_j$

The edges of a graph are transitive (ordered) if for every $(i,j) ,(j,k) \in  E \implies (i,k) \in E$

> Prove the the complement $\hat G$ of  $G$ is a permutation graph
>   and $G$ is transitive

What I got: Since the complement $\hat G$ of $G$ contains all the edges which $G$ does not contain.

$i<j$ and $\pi_i \le\pi_j$ then $(i,j) \in \hat G$

which permutation does that correspond to ?

For the second part:

$$i \lt j \quad \pi_i \gt \pi_j$$
$$j \lt k \quad \pi_j \gt \pi_k$$
$$\implies$$

$$i\lt j \lt k \quad \pi_i\gt\pi_j \gt\pi_k$$

so the permutation graph is transitive (because $\pi$ is)

Would appreciate any help with the first part

Answer (score 1):

For 1), take the reverse of the permutation.  Note that the condition $\pi_i \le\pi_j$ is equivalent to $\pi_i < \pi_j,$ because $\pi$ is a permutation, and $\pi_i \ne\pi_j$ when $i\ne j.